# Magento 2 send e-mail (order) notification to customer without cron

Tags: magento2, cron, email-scheduler

I need to limit some of the magento 2 cron job, one of them is send an email to customer:

[image]

can i make this cron job not running on cron?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in Magento 2 transactional emails can be sent "asynchronously," or without the cron. Stores > Settings > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails See [Magento User Guide - Sales Email](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/configuration/sales/sales-emails.html).